# Compute the angle of a triangle when 3 points are given

Tags: c#, geometry, 2d, angle

i have 3 Points ((x,y), (x', y'), (x'', y'')) and i want to find the angle in the 3 points
i also need to get a point when having the angle and 2 other points (but that shouldn't be a problem)

if it helps - i am working with c#

Comment: you can use the fact that xy = |x||y|cos(x^y) (x, y -- vectors, xy -- their scalar product)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879961/calculate-angle-from-two-points-and-a-direction-vector<BR>
Look at that question

Answer (score 1):

For a general, non right angle triangle, you need what is known as the [*Law of Cosines*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines). This allows you to calculate the internal angles at each corner of the triangle given the lengths of each side.  You can calculate the length of each side using the Pythagorean equality.

The second part of your question is not clearly specified.

Comment: i have a non right triangle - i know 3 points - 2 points are fixed and 1 point is the direction where one object is flying to. so i calculate the angle between this 3 points. i need to hit the object which moves to the direction that is given (everything has the same speed - so i only have to look that the angle is below 90 degrees). so i can say that alpha and beta have to be the same angle. when i have the angle i only need to calculate the point in which i have to shot my 3rd object.

Comment: and this makes me mad; this is what i actually have:
<br /><code>
//just to make it shorter
double angle = Math.Acos(dotprod / Math.Sqrt(len1sq * len2sq));
            len1sq = Math.Sqrt(len1sq);
            len1sq = (int)len1sq;
            int newX = 0, newY = 0;
            if (b.x > a.x) { newX = b.x - (int)len1sq; }
            if (b.x < a.x) { newX = b.x + (int)len1sq; }
            if (b.y > a.y) { newY = b.y - (int)len1sq; }
            if (b.y < a.y) { newY = b.y + (int)len1sq; }
            return new Point(newX, newY);
<code>

Answer (score 0):

Read the following:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions and http://jwbales.us/precal/part6/part6.2.html

cos A = ( b^2 + c^2 - a^2 ) / ( 2 bc )

cos B = ( a^2 + c^2 - b^2 ) / ( 2 ac )

cos C = ( a^2 + b^2 - c^2 ) / ( 2 ab )

then take the arccos on each of the values you get to find the angle.

Study trig, do research, and convert the above equations to code.

Comment: why do you repeat the formula 3 times? Once is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest would be to use the scalar product:

```
double dotprod = (x'' - x)*(x' - x) + (y'' - y)*(y' - y);
double len1 = sqrt((x' - x) * (x' - x) + (y' - y) * (y' - y));
double len2 = sqrt((x'' - x) * (x'' - x) + (y'' - y) * (y'' - y));
double angle = acos(dotprod/(len1*len2));
```

This should be faster than using the law of cosines.

Edit:
We can omit one `sqrt` if doing this way:

```
double dotprod = (x'' - x)*(x' - x) + (y'' - y)*(y' - y);
double len1squared = (x' - x) * (x' - x) + (y' - y) * (y' - y);
double len2squared = (x'' - x) * (x'' - x) + (y'' - y) * (y'' - y);
double angle = acos(dotprod/sqrt(len1squared*len2squared));
```

This calculation is basically the same as @David's.

Comment: whats the 'middle' point in this formular? because i have 2 endpoints and 1 point in the middle

Comment: It won't be faster. The `sqrt` calls will hurt. You don't do those with law of cosine. If you were concerned about speed you would re-write this with just a single call to `sqrt`, but even so law of cosines will be faster. Final point, could you explain the justification behind this method. Otherwise it just looks like magic to OP.

Comment: The angle is measured at `(x, y)`.

Comment: @David: how are you going to calculate `2bc` for the law of cosines without `sqrt`?

Comment: @Vlad Ah, got me there! One sqrt is enough though. My guess is that this magic formula you produce is equivalent to law of cosines since len1*len2 appears to be no more than `bc`, and then there's the `acos`.

Comment: @David: indeed, you and me calculate the same numerators and denominators, just mine has one multiplication less. Yours will be mine if substitute the coordinate values and simplify.

Comment: @David: as a mathematician, I state that the law of cosines and dot product are equivalent :-)

Comment: i only need to calculate this once so the performance doesnt really matter

Comment: @Vlad As a mathematician, I will now spend some time working out why your statement is correct.

Comment: @David: I use just x\dot y = |x||y|cos(x^y)

Comment: i guess the angle that comes out is in radians right?
well i only need to turn it back now x.x

Comment: is there a way i can contact u vlad just to solve this problem as fast as i can ? :/

Comment: @kafioin: there's a chat on stackoverflow: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Comment: now i have 2 points and the angle and i am searching for the 2nd endpoint.
i only need to convert the equation but whats the opposite of acos?

Comment: double dotDivLen = Math.Cos(angle); // = dotprod / sqrt(len1*len2) ---------
len1sq = (endP1.X - aP.X) * (endP1.X - aP.X) + (endP1.Y - aP.Y) * (endP1.Y - aP.Y);  ------
double sol = dotDivLen * Math.Sqrt(len1sq); // = dotprod/sqrt(len2)
------
this is what i actually got - but i still dont know how i can get x/y :/